# How to fix "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" (jQuery, Wordpress)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I imported `$` from **jQuery** in **Wp** for a search button and got Uncaught

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.

I used the word **jQuery** instead `$`, console was empty, but code still doesn't work. What did I do wrong?

**HTML button**

```
    <span class="search-trigger js-search-trigger"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
```

**JS**

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
class Search {
// 1. Describe, create, initiate our object
constructor(){
    this.openButton = $(".js-search-trigger");
    this.closeButton = $(".search-overlay__close");
    this.searchOverlay = $(".search-overlay");
    this.events();
} // 2.events
events(){
this.openButton.on("click", this.openOverlay.bind(this));
this.closeButton.on("click", this.closeOverlay.bind(this));
}// 3. methods (function, action...)
    openOverlay(){
    this.searchOverlay.addClass("search-overlay--active");
} 
closeOverlay(){
    this.searchOverlay.removeClass("search-overlay--active");
}    
}
```

**functions.php**

```
    wp_enqueue_script('script', 
    get_theme_file_uri('/js/modules/search.js'),                      
    array('jquery'), microtime(), true);
```

Expected result - click on search sign, it displays pop up window with search input. Click on close sign, it'll close.

Actual results - nothing happens. Console mistake Uncaught `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import.`

Answer (score 0):

Try importing jQuery as file or other method like require. It seems like your environment isn’t supporting import token.

Also if you’re going to use that file in web browser not PHP dependency to polyfill things like unsupported by most of web browser, use ES5 syntax instead of latest.